# What exactly is the meaning of a degenerate partial differential equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, parabolic-pde

I'm trying to understand the meaning of a degenerate partial differential equation. I've only found the definition by Giga in Surface Evolution equation but I wanted to ask if somebody knows another reference to this type of partial differential equations. And what does it mean if a partial differential equation is degenerate not in the sense of the definition but in the geometrical sense? What are the problems that we have to face by analyzibg these pde? Maybe there are good references to these questions too.

Comment: Where did you encounter these terms? I feel like there is some significant context missing

Comment: [FYR](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Degenerate_partial_differential_equation)

Comment: Note that you are asking essentially two questions: (1) what is a degenerate PDE (which is just a definition), and (2) The comment by Giga about geometric flows not degenerate in the geometric sense.

Comment: @supinf I assume it is found in the [book](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783764324308)

Comment: Yes it is found in the book referenced by Arctic Char. 1) Thanks for the reference, but I'm having a few difficulties with the definition for degenerate parabolic equation. What is the meaning of m? Is it the highest order in the pde so that in the example given we have m=2? And by "whose types degenerates in certain points of the domain of definition" they mean that the pde isn't well defined in these points? 2) What I thought Giga points out is that the geometric flow (MCF) leads to a highly degenerate pde, but this doesn't mean that the geometric flow is degenerate or am I mistaken?

Comment: for $u_t(x,t) - a(x)\Delta u(x,t)=0$, in $(0,1)\times (0,1)$, the usual (nondegenerate) case requires the uniform ellipticity: $a(x)\ge a_0 >0$ in $[0,1]$. The degenerate case means: degeneration on boundary if $a(0)=0$ (or $a(1)=0$) and interior degeneration if $a(x_0)=0$ for some $x_0 \in (0,1)$.

Comment: A system of partial differential equations (a system of dependent equations) is said to be degenerate if one (or more) equation of the system can be derived from the others, or is formed from a combination of them. In quantum mechanics, the degeneracy concern the states of a system (vectors) and their eigenvalues (energies). Degenerate states are a collection of states possessing the same eigenvalue (level of energy).